# Collect the data range

Tags: excel, vba, date, range

```
Sub test()
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
For j = 2 To 36
    If Year(Range("B24")) & Month(Range("B24")) = Year(Range("D" & j)) & Month(Range("D" & j)) Then

        ' this one
        Holidays = Range("D" & j)

    End If
Next j
End With
End Sub
```

Hi everyone, I would like to collect the same year and month between column B and column D, for example in the code, I want to find the year and month same with "B24", the answer I want is "D3:D8" (2002 February), how can I collect this data range ? could I write into the "Holidays" like the bold one?

Thanks for helping! Best wishes for you.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This should do what I think you want:

```
Sub test()
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
For j = 2 To 36
    If Year(.Range("B24")) & Month(.Range("B24")) = Year(.Range("D" & j)) & Month(.Range("D" & j)) Then
        
        If Holidays Is Nothing Then
            Set Holidays = .Range("D" & j)
        Else
            Set Holidays = Application.Union(Holidays, .Range("D" & j))
        End If
    End If
Next j
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: hi, when I run the code, it shows "type mismatch" in "Holidays" of "If Holidays Is Nothing Then"